# Finding the rule for a quadratic function with highest point $(6,30)$ and that passes through $(2, 28.4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, graphing-functions

How can I find the rule of this function?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the vertex is $(6,30)$, then the equation will be $y=30-a(x-6)^2$ for some $a>0$.

Can you now solve for $a$ knowing that $(2,28.4)$ is another point on the parabola?